# Getting a 100% Training Accuracy, but 60% Testing accuracy

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying different classifiers with different parameters and stuff on a dataset provided to us as part of a course project. We have to try and get the best performance on the dataset. The dataset is actually a reduced version of the [online news popularity](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/online+news+popularity)

I have tried the SVM, Random Forest, SVM with cross-validation with k = 5 and they all seem to give approximately 100% training accuracy, while the testing accuracy is between 60-70. I think the testing accuracy is fine, but the training accuracy bothers me.
I would say maybe it was a case of overfitting data but none of my classmates seem to be getting similar results so maybe the problem is with my code.

Here is the code for my cross-validation and random forest classifier. I  would be very grateful if you help me find out why I am getting such a high Training accuracy

```
def crossValidation(X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test, numSplits):
    skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True)
    Cs = np.logspace(-3, 3, 10)
    gammas = np.logspace(-3, 3, 10)

    ACC = np.zeros((10, 10))
    DEV = np.zeros((10, 10))

    for i, gamma in enumerate(gammas):
        for j, C in enumerate(Cs):
            acc = []
            for train_index, dev_index in skf.split(X_train, y_train):
                X_cv_train, X_cv_dev = X_train[train_index], X_train[dev_index]
                y_cv_train, y_cv_dev = y_train[train_index], y_train[dev_index]
                clf = SVC(C=C, kernel='rbf', gamma=gamma, )
                clf.fit(X_cv_train, y_cv_train)
                acc.append(accuracy_score(y_cv_dev, clf.predict(X_cv_dev)))

            ACC[i, j] = np.mean(acc)
            DEV[i, j] = np.std(acc)

    i, j = np.argwhere(ACC == np.max(ACC))[0]
    clf1 = SVC(C=Cs[j], kernel='rbf', gamma=gammas[i], decision_function_shape='ovr')
    clf1.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_predict_train = clf1.predict(X_train)
    y_pred_test = clf1.predict(X_test)
    print("Train Accuracy :: ", accuracy_score(y_train, y_predict_train))
    print("Test Accuracy  :: ", accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred_test))


def randomForestClassifier(X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test):
    """

    clf = RandomForestClassifier()
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_predict_train = clf.predict(X_train)
    y_pred_test = clf.predict(X_test)
    print("Train Accuracy :: ", accuracy_score(y_train, y_predict_train))
    print("Test Accuracy  :: ", accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred_test))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues about the problem, training accuracy and testing accuracy are significantly different.

1. Different distribution of training data and testing data.(because of selecting a part of the dataset)
2. Overfitting of the model to the training data.

Since you apply cross-validation, it seems that you should think about another solution.
I recommend that you apply some feature selection or feature reduction (like PCA) approaches to tackle the overfitting problem.

Comment: I tried PCA and variance threshold to reduce the dimensionality of the feature set. Pca isn't effective on this dataset, but the variance threshold reduces the dataset to 21 from 59 features. But it still doesn't change the training accuracy value. It still reaches a 100%

Comment: rouhollah ghasempour, Could you provide any links where dimension reduction or input vector reduction without any another modification would help to avoid over-fitting.

Comment: @AntonAlekseev This is one of the links I referred to. Dunno how relevant it is for you, but just in case. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html

Comment: @Tulika Asthana this question was for "rouhollah ghasempour", sorry for my misleading comment if so. But if your model ideally approximate any train data and you going to drop some information more-less usefull it can't lead to better result in ovetfitting problem. In this case you'll only get much more better approximation from model.

Comment: @AntonAlekseev. Based on No-free-launch-theorem, there is no method having the best performance in all problems. So, feature selection and reduction approaches may improve the performance of the classifier and may decrease its performance. You can find a simple case at the following link that shows that PCA increases the performance: https://towardsdatascience.com/dimensionality-reduction-does-pca-really-improve-classification-outcome-6e9ba21f0a32.

Comment: There are many approaches for feature reduction. you can find a good paper published by Hinton in Science journal with near 7000 citation that shows its importance. Hinton, Geoffrey E., and Ruslan R. Salakhutdinov. "Reducing the dimensionality of data with neural networks." science 313.5786 (2006): 504-507

Comment: @Tulika Asthana. In order to find propoer approach for your work, you should examine different solutions. There is no method that fits to all probelms. make more experiments with different algorithms and parameters. Also, you can try to use ensemble systems.

Comment: @rouhollah ghasempour Thank you for references but I have enough knowledge about DR and PCA particularly and how it rise performance. But how "feature reduction (like PCA) approaches to tackle the overfitting problem" would work? I don't understand.

Comment: @AntonAlekseev there is a relation between curse of dimensionality and overfitting. http://www.visiondummy.com/2014/04/curse-dimensionality-affect-classification/. In machine learning, we should know the best representation. In some cases that the representation is proper, DR may cause the model to overfit.